# Enabling Jumbo Frame on Cisco 2960G

Tags: cisco, switch, jumboframes

I'm having issue with enabling jumbo frame on my Cisco 2960G.

Here is what I tried, and what I got:

```
Switch(config)#system mtu jumbo 9000
vb:: Read-only file system
Changes to the system jumbo MTU will not take effect until the next reload is done
Switch(config)#exit
Switch#sh sys mtu
System MTU size is 1500 bytes
System Jumbo MTU size is 1500 bytes
On next reload, System Jumbo MTU will be 9000 bytes
System Alternate MTU size is 1500 bytes
Routing MTU size is 1500 bytes
Switch#reload
System configuration has been modified. Save? [yes/no]:y
```

[…reload of switch…]

```
Switch#sh sys mtu
System MTU size is 1500 bytes
System Jumbo MTU size is 1500 bytes
System Alternate MTU size is 1500 bytes
Routing MTU size is 1500 bytes
```

As you can see, I got "vb:: Read-only file system" that doesn't sounds good.

So I tried different thing (upgrading from 12.2(44)SE6  to 12.2(55)SE5 and 12.2(58)SE2
I tried to fsck the flash card, and then I tried to reset with the flash_init followed by format flash and upload the iOS in xmodem... I'm not sure if I'm doing everything good, but I still get those "vb:: Read-only file system"...

Another strange example:

```
Switch(config)#boot system flash:c2960-lanbasek9-mz.122-58.SE2.bin
vb:: Read-only file system
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive research, here is the solution (sorry it's in french: http://osdir.com/ml/org.operators.frnog/2007-11/msg00259.html)

To debrief, it's a bug after a password recovery attempt. You need to manually set the file system in recovery mode: 
"set_bs vb: rw"

after everything is ok.